# a little help on how to update Mingw?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, c++11, mingw

i've downlaoded and installed latest mingw from the mingw site, now i want to update it to the new Mingw 4.8 from source forge, these are the contents:

Mingw from mingw.org:
folders:

- Bin
- doc
- include
- lib
- libexec
- mingw32
- share
- var

files:

- unins000.dat
- unin000.exe

==================================================================================

on the one i got from source forge:

folders:

- bin
- etc
- doc
- include
- licenses
- lib
- opt
- libexec
- x86_64-w64-mingw32
- share
- var

files:

- info.txt
- versions.txt

==================================================================================

i've searched for the last 5 hours and i end up with nothing, whenever i drop some files from the SF mingw to the Mingw.org's mingw folder, everything starts to fail, please help! all i wanted in the first place was to get C++11 which i heard was supported in MinGW 4.8.

thank you.

Comment: In those 5 hours you could uninstall the previous version and install the new one multiple times.

Comment: [This is where I always get my mingw from.](http://nuwen.net/)  Braindead simple to install, and comes with boost, plus many other goodies.  By the way, if by "supported" you mean full compliance, then no, GCC does not support C++11.  If you mean, "supports many features", then 4.7 does that too, just a few features less.

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin Lindley, you were right about it, God bless you! and I got quite lucky since im just in time, they have updated the MinGW distro with gcc 4.8, thank you! for those who will stumble upon this question, go here:

http://nuwen.net/mingw.html